# Auto-indent Between Tags in Brackets

Tags: adobe-brackets, auto-indent

Typing `<html>` automatically creates `</html>` after your cursor in Brackets:

[image]

But when you press enter it just puts the closing tag on the next line:

[image]

To begin adding code I need to press (<kbd>enter</kbd> `*` 2), <kbd>up arrow</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd> (too many steps).

---

How can I do this automatically so that pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> results in:

[image]

Couldn't find an extension that does this.

This works natively in CSS, why not in HTML?

Comment: You can also try Enter followed by Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Comment: Amazing tip, thank you! Added to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### UPDATE: [arsakasra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2177290/arsakasra)'s comment works really well!

Press <kbd>enter</kbd> followed by (<kbd>CMD</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> on PC) + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>

---

I've been playing around with the preferences and added the following to my `brackets.json` file (access in Menu Bar: Debug: "Open Preferences File").

```
"closeTags": {
    "dontCloseTags": ["br", "hr", "img", "input", "link", "meta", "area", "base", "col", "command", "embed", "keygen", "param", "source", "track", "wbr"],
    "indentTags": ["ul", "ol", "div", "section", "table", "tr"],
    }
```

- `dontCloseTags` are tags such as `<br>` which shouldn't be closed.
- `indentTags` are tags that you want to automatically create a new
  indented line - add more as needed!
- (any tags that aren't in above arrays will self-close on the
  same line)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/shumpei/brackets-autoindent-extension

Here is a link for an extension on the Brackets that add the Auto-Indent feature.

Comment: Re: atom, I like brackets’ live preview feature although I could probably achieve with an atom extension.

Comment: Re: brackets extension - Are you sure that doesn’t indent code you’ve already written? I found a few extensions that did that but I want it to happen as I’m typing.

Comment: I personally use Atom and I know they have a feature where you can Auto-Indent by going to Edit > Lines > Auto Indent.  I would assume Brackets has something similar.  It detects the existing indentation and adjusts accordingly.

Comment: Tried looking in brackets settings but they’re written in plain text with booleans for toggling features...skimmed but didn’t find. I mainly use atom too but brackets is cool for web

Comment: The only thing I can find is that you need an extension to auto-indent.  Here is a link to another highly recommended one.  https://github.com/ahuth/brackets-indentator

Comment: Same response as “re: brackets extension” above